# LDAP filter not returning appropriate number of entries

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

In PHP, my filter: `(&(objectClass=*)(memberOf=CN=MyGroup,...))`

This returns 3 entries.

In AD Explorer, it returns 8 entries - which is correct.

Why would it work properly in AD Explorer, but not in PHP?

Comment: This does not answer the question, but consider not using the present filter `objectClass=*`. All entries have at least one `objectClass` present, therefore, the present filter component of `objectClass` is not necessary, and may affect the response time of the search.

Comment: @terrygardner Thanks. I will change this accordingly. I was previously using user and person objectClasses, but wanted to make sure the other entries weren't under a different objectClasses (beginner at writing filters).

Comment: @TerryGardner see my answer... I was messing around in ADExplorer and all of a sudden, noticed a slight difference with the missing entries.

Comment: @TerryGardner will do, as soon as the 2 days of waiting are up... LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just need to broaden the search DN.

For instance, I was using a similar DN:
`OU=A,OU=B,OU=C,DC=D,DC=E,DC=F`

It turns out that the missing users were in a different DN, by broadening it more, it worked:
`OU=C,DC=D,DC=E,DC=F`